# Jquery Fade in/out not working on first hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to utilize the fade in/out jquery plugin. With the help of others here yesterday, I got it almost working perfectly. But the fade in effect doesn't seem to work on the first time I hover over the div. It works after second and subsequent hovers. And the fade out doesn't seem to work at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6gRp/4/

NOTE: Nothing is supposed to happen when you hover over step 1. But the color blocks are supposed to fade in/out when you hover over the other steps. I'm more of a designer so I'm not sure why the animation doesn't happen on the first hover. Is this the proper way to do the JS code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div.secure").hover(
        function() {
            $("div.secure-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $("div.secure-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );

    $("div.cash").hover(
        function() {
            $("div.steps-hover.cash-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $("div.steps-hover.cash-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );

    $("div.credit").hover(
        function() {
            $("div.credit-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $("div.credit-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );

});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your css you have all -hover like this "div.cash:hover div.cash-hover"

```
div.default, div.cash:hover div.cash-hover, div.secure:hover div.secure-hover, div.credit:hover div.credit-hover{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 180px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 234px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

it sets the properties width,height,...etc only when you have hover on the element div.cash if you change it like this "div.cash-hover"

```
div.default, div.cash-hover,div.secure-hover, div.credit-hover{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 180px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 234px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: auto;
}
//set all -hover to display none
div.cash-hover, div.secure-hover, div.credit-hover {
    display: none;
}
```

you set the properties on div.cash-hover from the begining so $("div.cash").hover can animate the opacity http://jsfiddle.net/c6gRp/6/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify anything for div.online-hover.

```
$("div.online").hover(
function () {
    $("div.online-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeIn('slow');
},
function () {
    $("div.online-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6gRp/5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Online is step 1 so it shouldn't do anything when you hover over it, so that's why I didn't include it in the function. I went to your updated JSfiddle and it still doesn't fade in on the first hover, only second and subsequent.